# Flutter Compiler error message pod files error

Tags: flutter, dart, podfile

am just new for flutter and when am trying to build the app it keep giving
me this error

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone Xʀ in debug mode...


Compiler message:
../../../Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:55:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add' has
fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
void add(String name, value) {
   ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:694:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
void add(String name, Object value,
   ^
../../../Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:70:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.set' has
fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
void set(String name, Object value) {
   ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:703:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
void set(String name, Object value,
   ^


Upgrading project.pbxproj                   
Running pod install...                                                  
2912.0s (!)    


Warning: Podfile is out of date
This can cause a mismatched version of Flutter to be embedded in your app, which may result in App Store submission rejection or crashes.
If you have local Podfile edits you would like to keep, see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/24641 for instructions.
To regenerate the Podfile, run:
rm iOS/Podfile


Running Xcode build...                                                  
                                               
Xcode build done.                                           160.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
** BUILD FAILED **

Xcode's output:
↳
1 warning generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:19:10: warning: non-portable
 path to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on  disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
 /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2- mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:20:10: warning: non-portable
path to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Type.pbobjc.m:21:10: warning: non-portable
path to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
3 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning:
non-portable path to file '<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>

3 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning:
non-portable path to file '<protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
1 warning generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable
path to file '<protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
1 warning generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable
path to file '<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
1 warning generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable path
to file '<protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.m:18:10: warning: non-portable path
to file '<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Api.pbobjc.m:19:10: warning: non-portable path
to file '<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
3 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/google/protobuf/Any.pbobjc.m:17:10: warning: non-portable path
to file '<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
1 warning generated.
In file included from /Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.m:26:
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter
'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean
'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
4 warnings generated.
In file included from /Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:2:
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:328:19: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param sharedStyle
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:25: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: warning: parameter
'allowTapToDismiss' not found in the function declaration [-Wdocumentation]
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:343:9: note: did you mean
'tapToDismissEnabled'?
 @param allowTapToDismiss
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        tapToDismissEnabled
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/UIView+Toast.h:362:20: warning: empty paragraph
passed to '@param' command [-Wdocumentation]
 @param queueEnabled
 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:19:23: warning: unused
variable 'viewController' [-Wunused-variable]
    UIViewController *viewController =
                      ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:70:21: warning: unused
variable 'topPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat topPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.top;
                    ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:71:21: warning: unused
variable 'bottomPadding' [-Wunused-variable]
            CGFloat bottomPadding = window.safeAreaInsets.bottom;
                    ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/fluttertoast-3.1.3/ios/Classes/FluttertoastPlugin.m:48:19: warning: unused
variable 'size' [-Wunused-variable]
        NSNumber *size = call.arguments[@"size"];
                  ^
8 warnings generated.
2 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:32:18: warning: unused variable 'a'
[-Wunused-variable]
        uint8_t *a = starting_pointer + i + 3;
                 ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:57:18: warning: unused variable 'a'
[-Wunused-variable]
        uint8_t *a = starting_pointer + i + 3;
                 ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:84:12: warning: unused variable
'DEG_TO_RAD' [-Wunused-variable]
    double DEG_TO_RAD = 0.0174532925;
           ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:122:27: warning: variable 'br' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         r_rep = (r_rep + br) * wr;
                          ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:99:14: note: initialize the variable 'br'
to silence this warning
    double br, bg, bb;
             ^
              = 0.0
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:122:33: warning: variable 'wr' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         r_rep = (r_rep + br) * wr;
                                ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:100:14: note: initialize the variable 'wr'
to silence this warning
    double wr, wg, wb;
             ^
              = 0.0
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:123:27: warning: variable 'bg' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         g_rep = (g_rep + bg) * wg;
                          ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:99:18: note: initialize the variable 'bg'
to silence this warning
    double br, bg, bb;
                 ^
                  = 0.0
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:123:33: warning: variable 'wg' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         g_rep = (g_rep + bg) * wg;
                                ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:100:18: note: initialize the variable 'wg'
to silence this warning
    double wr, wg, wb;
                 ^
                  = 0.0
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:124:27: warning: variable 'bb' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         b_rep = (b_rep + bb) * wb;
                          ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:99:22: note: initialize the variable 'bb'
to silence this warning
    double br, bg, bb;
                     ^
                      = 0.0
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:124:33: warning: variable 'wb' may be
uninitialized when used here [-Wconditional-uninitialized]
         b_rep = (b_rep + bb) * wb;
                                ^~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/bitmap-0.0.5/ios/Classes/bitmap.cpp:100:22: note: initialize the variable 'wb'
to silence this warning
    double wr, wg, wb;
                     ^
                      = 0.0
9 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:73:53: warning:
incompatible pointer types sending 'FlutterEngine *' to parameter of type 'NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger> * _Nonnull'
[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
                                    binaryMessenger:_headlessRunner];
                                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In module 'Flutter' imported from
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.h:1:
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/.symlinks/flutter/ios/Flutter.framework/Headers/FlutterChannels.h:178:74: note: passing
argument to parameter 'messenger' here
                      binaryMessenger:(NSObject<FlutterBinaryMessenger>*)messenger;
                                                                         ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:273:15: warning:
unused variable 'url' [-Wunused-variable]
    NSString *url = dict[KEY_URL];
              ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:863:52: warning:
incompatible pointer types sending 'NSURLSessionTask *' to parameter of type 'NSURLSessionDownloadTask *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        NSString *taskId = [self identifierForTask:task ofSession:session];
                                                   ^~~~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:160:60: note:
passing argument to parameter 'task' here
- (NSString*)identifierForTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask*) task ofSession:(NSURLSession *)session
                                                           ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_downloader-1.3.1/ios/Classes/FlutterDownloaderPlugin.m:904:51: warning:
block implicitly retains 'self'; explicitly mention 'self' to indicate this is intended behavior [-Wimplicit-retain-self]
                    localNotification.alertBody = _allFilesDownloadedMsg;
                                                  ^
                                                  self->
4 warnings generated.
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.0.7/ios/Classes/GoogleSignInPlugin.m:137:41: warning:
'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
  NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/google_sign_in/google_sign_in-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UI
Kit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:518:51: note: 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' has been marked as being introduced in iOS
9.0 here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
UIKIT_EXTERN UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey const UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey NS_SWIFT_NAME(sourceApplication)
API_AVAILABLE(ios(9.0));   // value is an NSString containing the bundle ID of the originating application; non-nil if the originating
application and this application share the same team identifier
                                                  ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.0.7/ios/Classes/GoogleSignInPlugin.m:137:41: note: enclose
'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey' in an @available check to silence this warning
  NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.0.7/ios/Classes/GoogleSignInPlugin.m:138:27: warning:
'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey' is only available on iOS 9.0 or newer [-Wunguarded-availability]
  id annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey];
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Target Support
Files/google_sign_in/google_sign_in-prefix.pch:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator13.4.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UI
Kit.framework/Headers/UIApplication.h:519:51: note: 'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey' has been marked as being introduced in iOS 9.0
here, but the deployment target is iOS 8.0.0
UIKIT_EXTERN UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey const UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey NS_SWIFT_NAME(annotation) API_AVAILABLE(ios(9.0));
// value is a property-list typed object corresponding to what the originating application passed in UIDocumentInteractionController's annotation
property
                                                  ^
/Users/haptome/Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/google_sign_in-4.0.7/ios/Classes/GoogleSignInPlugin.m:138:27: note: enclose
'UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey' in an @available check to silence this warning
  id annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey];
                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2 warnings generated.
While building module 'Protobuf' imported from
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.m:27:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Protobuf/Protobuf-umbrella.h:28:
In file included from /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:44:
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:40:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:41:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBWellKnownTypes.h:42:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
While building module 'Protobuf' imported from
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/FirebaseMessaging/Firebase/Messaging/Protos/GtalkExtensions.pbobjc.m:27:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/Protobuf/Protobuf-umbrella.h:28:
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:55:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Any.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:56:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Api.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:57:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Duration.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:58:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Empty.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:59:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/FieldMask.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:60:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/SourceContext.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:61:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Struct.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:62:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Timestamp.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:63:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Type.pbobjc.h>
/Users/haptome/Downloads/musicfile2-mainfile/musicapp/ios/Pods/Protobuf/objectivec/GPBProtocolBuffers.h:64:10: warning: non-portable path to file
'<protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>'; specified path differs in case from file name on disk [-Wnonportable-include-path]
 #import <Protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
         <protobuf/Wrappers.pbobjc.h>
13 warnings generated.
13 warnings generated.

Compiler message:
../../../Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:55:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.add'
has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.add'.
  void add(String name, value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:694:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('add').
  void add(String name, Object value,
       ^
../../../Library/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/dio-2.2.2/lib/src/dio_http_headers.dart:70:8: Error: The method 'DioHttpHeaders.set'
has fewer named arguments than those of overridden method 'HttpHeaders.set'.
  void set(String name, Object value) {
       ^
org-dartlang-sdk:///third_party/dart/sdk/lib/_http/http.dart:703:8: Context: This is the overridden method ('set').
  void set(String name, Object value,
       ^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
build failed.
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
warning: Mapping architecture armv7 to i386. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured
correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')
warning: Mapping architecture arm64 to x86_64. Ensure that this target's Architectures and Valid Architectures build settings are configured
correctly for the iOS Simulator platform. (in target 'image_picker' from project 'Pods')

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone Xʀ.
```

and i tried

```
rm ios/Podfile
```

and

```
flutter run
```

but it gave me the same error like the above one I try many things but still it want work.
Does someone knows what can cause the problem? Maybe it's because it is run on iOS or something.
so please help me out with this one.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you the solution, I'm facing same issue.

Comment: if you use "dio" package just update it to the latest version if not just update the hole pubspec.yaml

Answer (score 0):

please try this：

step 1 :

make sure your Flutter version

ex: 1.22

step 2 :

find latest dio pub version in : https://pub.dev/

ex: 3.x

step 3 :

check your pubspec.yaml file in your project

find dio and check version

step 4 :

if your pubspec.yaml file dio version is not matching.

edit your pubspec.yaml dio verison

ex :

```
dio : ^3.0.0
```

step 5 :

run this in your Flutter project path terminal

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

done !

It work for me